# Is it possible to create a dummy sparse matrix with no rows or columns in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm working with arrays of sparse matrices using [SciPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciPy), and sometimes some of the matrices have no rows or columns (that is, `shape = (0,0)`). I would like my various other functions to just ignore these matrices, or do some other smart default action.

It seems I can't use any of the sparse matrix formats, because they complain about "invalid shape". For some reason `matrix([])` and `matrix([[]])` have `shape = (1,0)`, so these are not much good (actually, is that a bug? It makes little sense...).

I know that I could use `None`, `[]`, `array([])` or something similar. However standard matrix manipulation functions will fail when handed these, meaning I would need to scatter

```
if block is not None:
```

or similar throughout my code.

Is there a matrix class that I've missed which will allow me to handle these cases gracefully?

---

For anyone curious: this comes out of chopping up a finite element [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) into blocks by the type of variable. Some of these variables may be pinned (fixed to a constant value), and so have no derivatives. Hence no entries in the Jacobian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

matrix([[]]) -> shape = (1,0) makes perfect sense; you gave it one row, with zero columns; how is numpy supposed to guess what you really wanted was zero rows instead?

All array creation functions such as np.zeros((0,0)) work for your purposes.

Comment: Oh, that remark was meant to refer to `matrix([])` having `shape (1,0)` (I added the part about `matrix([[]])` later).

Comment: Aha, np.zeros((0, 0)) works. I guess only array (and not the matrix or sparse matrix formats) can have shape (0,0) in my version of scipy.

Comment: It does actually, thanks! I'm using `m = sp.matrix(sp.zeros((0,0))); m.nnz = 0` as a temporary hack until I get around to updating my Linux distribution or installing a newer scipy.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can do

```
from scipy import sparse
result = sparse.eye(0)
# result.shape = (0, 0)
```

Comment: Maybe my version of numpy is too old, because 1) `sparse.eye` takes minimum two arguments for me and 2) doing `sparse.eye(0,0)` gives me `ValueError: invalid shape`. My `np.version.version = 1.7.1`.

Comment: I have the same numpy version and scipy `0.13.0`. You could try `x = np.zeros((0, 0)); sparse.csr_matrix(x)` or upgrade to the latest Scipy if that's the issue

Comment: Using `np.zeroes((0,0))` inside `sparse.csr_matrix()` gives the same `invalid shape` error.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to create a 0x0 sparse matrix.  For example,

```
In [16]: from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, coo_matrix, dok_matrix, eye

In [17]: csr_matrix(([], [[],[]]), shape=(0,0))
Out[17]: 
<0x0 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [18]: coo_matrix(([],[[],[]]), shape=(0,0))
Out[18]: 
<0x0 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 0 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [19]: dok_matrix((0,0))
Out[19]: 
<0x0 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 0 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>

In [20]: eye(0)
Out[20]: 
<0x0 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 0 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>

In [21]: csr_matrix(np.zeros((0, 0)))
Out[21]: 
<0x0 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

You said you were chopping up a Jacobian matrix.  If you index
a sparse matrix with slices that have zero length, you'll get
a 0x0 result:

```
In [22]: a = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(10,10))

In [23]: m = csr_matrix(a)

In [24]: m[3:3, 3:3]
Out[24]: 
<0x0 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

(I'm using scipy 0.13.2.)

It is possible that some sparse operations will not handle a 0x0 matrix properly, and that might be a bug.  If you have some examples, could you add them to your question?

Comment: I definitely need to update scipy! The first set of examples all give me `ValueError: invalid shape`. The second example gives me `IndexError: index out of bounds: 0<=3<10, 0<=3<10, 3<3`. I'm on version `'0.10.1'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below codes and it is easy.

import numpy as np
np.zeros((0,0))